# Finding/editing exact entry in file

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make changes to a file and I appear to need some help with regex. I have the following code:

```
    public delegate string UpdateAction(string contents);

    public static void UpdateFile(string file, UpdateAction m)
    {
        string contents = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            contents = reader.ReadToEnd();

        contents = m(contents);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            writer.WriteLine(contents);
    }

    public static void UpdateProperty(string file, string objectName, string property, string value)
    {
        UpdateFile(file, delegate(string contents)
        {
            string propertyPattern = "(\"" + property + "\".*?\")(.*?)(\")";
            string pattern = "(\"?)" + objectName + "(\"?)(\n|\r|\r\n)(.*?){(.*?)}";
            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
            contents = new Regex(pattern, options).Replace(contents, (MatchEvaluator)(m => new Regex(propertyPattern, options).Replace(m.Value, delegate(Match propertyMatch)
                {
                    string str = propertyMatch.Value;
                    if (propertyMatch.Groups.Count > 3)
                    {
                        str = propertyMatch.Groups[1] + value + propertyMatch.Groups[3];
                    }

                    return str;
                })));

            return contents;
        });
    }
```

An example file would look something like this:

```
"Resource/HudLayout.res"
{
    Circle
    {
        "visible"       "0"
        "enabled"       "0"
        "controlName"   "CExLabel"
        "fieldName"     "Circle"
        "zpos"          "2"
        "xpos"          "c-100"
        "ypos"          "c-96"
        "wide"          "201"
        "tall"          "200"
        "font"          "Crosshairs34"  //CrosshairsOutline34
        "labelText"     "9"
        "textAlignment" "center"    
        "fgcolor"       "Crosshair"
    }
    CircleDot
    {
        "visible"       "0"
        "enabled"       "0"
        "controlName"   "CExLabel"
        "fieldName"     "CircleDot"
        "zpos"          "2"
        "xpos"          "c-100"
        "ypos"          "c-96"
        "wide"          "201"
        "tall"          "200"
        "font"          "Crosshairs34"  //CrosshairsOutline34
        "labelText"     "8"
        "textAlignment" "center"    
        "fgcolor"       "Crosshair"
    }
    QuarterCircle
    {
        "visible"       "0"
        "enabled"       "0"
        "controlName"   "CExLabel"
        "fieldName"     "QuarterCircle"
        "zpos"          "2"
        "xpos"          "c-100"
        "ypos"          "c-98"
        "wide"          "201"
        "tall"          "200"
        "font"          "Crosshairs34"  //CrosshairsOutline34
        "labelText"     "w"
        "textAlignment" "center"    
        "fgcolor"       "Crosshair"
    }
}
```

When I call `UpdateProperty(@"C:\file.res", "Circle", "enabled", "1");` it's matching **Circle** and Quarter**Circle** and setting the `enabled` property to `1` for both. I'm not great with regex and was wondering what pattern I should be using to only catch the object I'm searching for.

Comment: What format this file is? and why are you even using this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexes were not formed correctly because you forgot to escape the slashes (that is why you'd rather use verbatim string literals when defining a regex pattern), and the main problem was with the missing word boundaries `\b`.

Here is an update that should work (tested, and only expected entry is modified):

```
string propertyPattern = @"(""\b" + Regex.Escape(property) + @"\b"".*?"")(.*?)("")";
string pattern = @"(""?)\b" + Regex.Escape(objectName) + @"\b(""?)(\r\n|\n|\r)(.*?){(.*?)}";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
```

I also doubt you need to specify the `Multiline` flag since you are not using `^` and `$` in your patterns.

I also added `Regex.Escape(property)` just in case there are any special characters in the argument you pass (then there can be a problem with `\b`, but I hope it won't be the case).

Also, to match any type of newline, you need to use `(\r\n|\n|\r)` where the longest part should come first, or it will never be tested against.

Comment: Please check if this works for you. I tested in Visual Studio 2012, and obtained expected results (only `Circle`*enabled* key value was set to `1`).

Answer (score 1):

Update this line (added `\\W` pattern):

```
string pattern = "\\W(\"?)" + objectName + "(\"?)(\n|\r|\r\n)(.*?){(.*?)}";
```